# Joomla 3 : Multimedia articles (article with photo, with video, multi photos)

Tags: html, joomla, joomla3.0, article

I'm trying to use Joomla for the first time, I have a small idea about models and extensions, I have been playing with it for a week.

but what I couldn't find is an extension that allow me to add articles with video and/or photos, and also deploy them in the homepage.

I know that I can put an entry Image, but that's not what I seek.

and also the user of this system will not have a knowledge in html or something like that.

this is a picture example of what I want:

[image: Articles Example]

I need to have a news section which has articles with images and/or video with the text for sure.

is there an extension that will allow me to do this?

or should I look for a stand alone script and put it in the homepage in iFrame ?

please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain in words what you want to achieve? Your image looks like a blog, featured or tags layout.

Comment: @Elin Yes sure, I did update my question, may thanks; it is a news section containing articles with photos or videos.

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the blog layouts?

Comment: @Elin I have no Idea what that is, I'm now using K2 extension and designing the blocks manually =(, its hard but I hope it works. Thanks =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use K2 it allows you to join videos and images to articles and display them with a lot of layout options. you can find K2 [here](http://getk2.org/index.php).

Comment: thank you very much, this seems to be the best option for me.